# Вопрос по чекбоксам и PHP. Почему не задаётся значение?

Tags: php

Всем привет. На странице есть 2 чекбокса:

```
<input name="emailused" id="emailused" type="checkbox" value="1"><label           
for="emailused">Текст чекбокса 1</label><br>
<input name="telused" id="telused" type="checkbox" value="1">
<label for="telused">Текст чекбокса 2</label>
```

А также PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['emailused'])) {$emailused = $_POST['emailused'];  
if ($emailused == '')   {$emailused = '0';}}

if (isset($_POST['telused']))   {$telused = $_POST['telused'];      
if ($telused == '')     {$telused = '0';}}
```

Если чекбокс выбран, то всё нормально, переменным задаётся единичка.
Но если чекбокс не выбран, то переменные пустые. Я пустым переменным задаю нулевое значение. Но оно почему-то не задаётся. В чём может быть причина, и как исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так пробовали? И что это у вас за логика в if ?

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST);
    echo "</pre>";
    if (isset($_POST['emailused'])) {
        $emailused = $_POST['emailused'];
    }
    else {
        $emailused = '0';
    }

    if (isset($_POST['telused'])) {
        $telused = $_POST['telused'];
    }
    else {
        $telused = '0';
    }

    echo "emailused = ".$emailused."<br />";
    echo "telused = ".$telused;
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. То, что надо. А я сам что-то не догадался. Логика в условиях из курса Попова PHP+MySQL.

Comment: Вот Вам два источника и больше не тратьте своё время на такие видеокурсы ;)
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp

А если уж очень хочется видео смотреть, го ту lynda.com, если жалко денег можно беспатно найти эти же курсы на thepiratebay например

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки. Осталось только английский выучить.

Comment: Технический анг. надо уже знать, это серьёзно помогает в изучении ЯП. =)
там есть свич на русский
http://www.php.net/manual/ru/index.php